# Como enviar um arquivo maior que 10MB sem ter acesso ao php.ini?

Tags: php, htaccess, upload

É o seguinte: Minha hospedagem gratuita de arquivos me dá acesso à ver informações do arquivo php.ini, mas não posso modificar ele, já tentei criar um php.ini na pasta `htdocs` mas não adiantou, tentei adicionar isso no `.htaccess` e não funcionou:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 40M
php_value post_max_size 42M
```

Informações do PHP Info que podem ser úteis:

```
Propriedade                       Valor original    Valor do servidor
================================= ================= =================
file_uploads                      On                On
max_execution_time                20                30
max_file_uploads                  20                20
post_max_size                     20M               20M
upload_max_filesize               10M               10M
upload_tmp_dir                    /tmp              /tmp
session.upload_progress.cleanup   On                On
session.upload_progress.enabled   On                On
session.upload_progress.freq      1%                1%
```

Eu só preciso colocar para fazer upload com mais de **10mb**, mas minha hospedagem não permite mais que isso. O que posso fazer?

Comment: dependendo do servidor, dá pra fazer um .user.ini no lugar do .htaccess - depende como o PHP foi configurado (se é módulo ou fcgi). No caso o formato da linha de config dentro desse ini seria `upload_max_filesize = 20M` por exemplo.

Comment: Então, acontece que *o arquivo php.ini está oculto dentro do servidor interno da hospedagem e não tenho acesso à ele.* As informações foram retiradas através do "PHP Info" no cPanel.

Comment: o `.user.ini` é lido na pasta do PHP quando a opção está habilitada e roda como fcgi - seria um "equivalente" do .htaccess quando o PHP não é módulo. http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php

Comment: Me desculpe a ignorância, mas como vejo se o arquivo está habilitado? Ele funciona como o php.ini?

Comment: Achei as propriedades ```user_ini.cache_ttl = 300``` e ```user_ini.filename = ".user.ini"```. Isto significa algo?

Comment: Experimente criar um arquivo texto `.user.ini` com `upload_max_filesize = 50M` na pasta do sistema de upload, aguarde os 300 segundos e teste se algo mudou no upload.

Comment: @Bacco tentei e tentei, não funcionou... o arquivo foi criado na pasta raiz do site... :\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ini_set('post_max_size', '64M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '64M');`